# Change Settings/Preference Programmatically of iPhone Messages App

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, cydia, cydia-substrate

I want to change iPhone's Messages notification preference, programmatically in a **jailbreak app**.  Any private API can be used and the app is not for the AppStore, so kindly don't say that *"app will not be approved by Apple"*.

**How can I turn off the notification for incoming messages?**

Comment: There isn't a question here. You need to post the code you've tried so far and what you want to achieve

Comment: @SuhailPatel: Actually, I believe it's legit question and I don't think  "tried so far" is applicable for such case. Quite often finding these private api's requires a lot of reverse engineering and almost no coding.

Comment: @SuhailPatel: Seems like “what you want to achieve” is covered pretty well in the question.

Comment: This kind of question I think demonstrates a particular failing of the general SO community's desire for *"what have you tried?"*.  Some topics just don't have much good documentation out there, and until a question is asked here, you won't even know where to start.  It certainly doesn't mean the question's asker is lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your app entitlements `com.apple.bulletinboard.settings` key with bool value equal to `YES`.
Link to private BulletinBoard.framework. It contains all required classes.

We are going to work with an instance of `BBSettingsGateway`

```
BBSettingsGateway* settings = [[BBSettingsGateway alloc] init];
```

Getting all notification preferences

```
[settings getSectionInfoWithCompletion:^(NSArray* sections){
}];
```

`sections` will contain array of `BBSectionInfo` objects. Theirs `sectionID` property contains bundle id of target app. Search for `com.apple.MobileSMS` to find messages app preferences.

`BBSectionInfo` contains all notifications preferences. For example, you can disable all notifications like this

```
messagesAppSectionInfo.showsInNotificationCenter = NO;
```

Applying changes

```
[settings setSectionInfo:messagesAppSectionInfo forSectionID:@"com.apple.MobileSMS"];
```

And complete example to disable all notifications for messages app:

```
BBSettingsGateway* settings = [[BBSettingsGateway alloc] init];
[settings getSectionInfoWithCompletion:^(NSArray* sections){
    for (BBSectionInfo* info in sections)
    {
        if ([info.sectionID isEqualToString:@"com.apple.MobileSMS"])
        {
            info.showsInNotificationCenter = NO;
            [settings setSectionInfo:info forSectionID:@"com.apple.MobileSMS"];
            break;
        }
    }
}];
```